# How to ask do you wan to unlock this account in Powershell (Yes/No)

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm new with powershell and i'm asking how do you can prompt question after when you have pull out the user information from AD in to variable $User

**Example:**

```
$User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input employee ID'
$LockedOut = Get-ADUser $User -Property LockedOut | foreach { $_.LockedOut }
Write-Output "Account Locked: $($LockedOut)"
```

> Account Locked: False

How i'm able to:
It should check is the account locked, if so it prompts question Do you want to unlock this user? (Y/N) 
If not it just prompts ok

Comment: Have a look at the docs for [Read-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would help:

```
# get the employeeID from user input. This will return a string; not a ADUser object
$empID = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input employee ID'
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($empID)) {
    # try and find the user having property 'EmployeeID' set to $empID
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$empID'" -Properties LockedOut, DisplayName
    if ($user) {
        # if we found the user and he/she is locked out
        if ($user.LockedOut) {
            $action = Read-Host -Prompt "Would you like to unlock user $($user.DisplayName)? (Y/N)"
            if ($action -eq 'Y') {
                $user | Unlock-ADAccount -Confirm:$false
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "User $($user.DisplayName) is not locked out" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find user with EmplyeeID '$empID'"
    }
}
```